# LNK1123 fatal error for VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I installed VC++ 2010 express and get LNK123 build error.
Even I un-install and install again stil the same.
Can anybody help me how to fix it?

The eror show as below

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: 轉換成 COFF 時失敗: 檔案無效或損毀

Comment: It is just a mistake in your project.  You are telling the linker to link a file that is not a valid .lib or .obj file.  The standard mistake is to try to link a .dll

Comment: VC++ 2010 is running in Dot NET 4. But whenever install Dot NET 4.5 will get this link error

Answer (score 0):

That Happened with me in a long time ago, But I Solved that issue, maybe the error is in your compiling, but there's a solution, Just download microsoft visual studio service pack 1 http://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=23691

and this will solve the problem right away, and a lot of problem else